# Adding class on hover to sibling element when multiple parents have same class

Tags: jquery

I am creating a mega menu, and am trying to add a class to a sibling element when the parent is hovered over. I have an example currently but it adds the class to every child element instead of only the one that has its parent being hovered over.

```js
$('.menu > .menu-item-has-children').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().find('.mega-menu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.mega-menu {
  background:green;
}
.mega-menu.active {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Parent</a>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Parent</a>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried the following, but get console errors relating to `preventDefault is not a function`:

```
$( ".menu > .menu-item-has-children" ).each(function(index,e) {
  $(this).on("mouseover", function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.mega-menu').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need javascript, you could use the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class and  [CSS `+` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) :

```css
.mega-menu {
  background:green;
}

a:hover + .mega-menu {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Parent</a>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Parent</a>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sibling</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh wow... I was massively overcomplicating things. Thanks a lot!